# What is the difference between fd obtaining from socket() and accept()?

Tags: websocket

I am trying to understand the difference between file descriptor from socket() and fd from accept().
If I read(fd,buffer,buffersize) from these two fds, what I will probably get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a server, the descriptor returned by `socket()` represents the local socket that is listening for clients, whereas the descriptor returned by `accept()` represents a specific client that is connected to the listening socket.  You cannot read/write using the listening descriptor, you must use the client descriptor instead.

Comment: Thanks! But what we can get if we read from the client descriptor?

Comment: You get whatever the client sends. What else are you expecting?

Comment: @If I have a terminal inputing "wget -i /home/Lily/testing/urls -O myres"  Do I get the whole command or just the " /home/Lily/testing/urls -O myres" part?  Thanks!

Comment: what does a terminal have to do with a socket?  Please stay on topic. If you want to ask something not related to the question at hand, please post a new question.